# Can i consume a context with another context?

Tags: reactjs, use-context

Im trying to update a state in a function to determine is my user is logged in or not, so that later i can conditionally route the user.

I have a LoginProvider, which has a callback function that stores the user data that comes from a decoded token. Inside that function i want to update the state of my other context provider which sets to true meaning that my user is logged in.

This is my LoginContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import AuthContext from "./AuthContext";

const LoginContext = createContext();

export function LoginProvider({ children}) {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({}) 
    const {setIsLoggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);

    function handleCallbackResponse(response){
        var userData = jwt_decode(response.credential); //Token with the login user Data
        setUser(userData); //Store user Data 
        setIsLoggedIn(true)
        /* console.log(userData) */
        document.getElementById('signInDiv').hidden = true;        
      }

    function handleSignOut(event) {
        setUser({}) //Empy the user Data
        
        document.getElementById('signInDiv').hidden = false;
    }  

    return(
        <LoginContext.Provider value={{user, handleCallbackResponse, handleSignOut}}>{children}</LoginContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default LoginContext
```

And this is my AuthContext.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext()

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn}}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext
```

So in my AuthContext i have my useState hook which has destructured variables isLoggedIn and setIsLoggedIn which its initial state is false. I want to send this state with my context provider and consume it in my LoginContext.js so that there i can update the state in my callBackResponse function and set it to true. Is this possible? Im trying to do this but i have the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...) is undefined
```

This error is produced at LoginContext.js

Answer (score 1):

To get around, you can try to set up `useEffect` with `user` as dependency:

```
// put this on the top level of component tree, like <App />

export default function App() {
  const { user } = useContext(LoginContext);
  const { setIsLoggedIn } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if( Object.keys(user).length ) { // if user is not empty
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
    }
  }, [user]) // listen to user state's change
}
```

This effectively makes `isLoggedIn` state "in sync" with `user` state. TBH, `Object.keys(user).length` is really ugly, that's because you initialized `user` state as empty object. If you initialize user as null, you can just do this `if(user) { ... }`.

BTW, since react provides us a declarative way to define UI, manipulating DOM element directly isn't really recommended, instead, you can conditionally render the `signInDiv` something like this:

```
{ Object.keys(user).length && <div id="signInDiv">my sign in div</div> }
```

On hindsight, you actually don't have to rely on `useEffect`, a better way is to move `handleCallbackResponse` and `handleSignOut` to a stand alone file (or a custom hook) and call respective setters so as to update both context state.